# What is the difference between jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. But using this I can only be left with my `.html`, `.js` and `.css` files. And In order to make it run in Smartphones, I need to create a stand alone application using toolkits such as PhoneGap. So, what if I develop the whole application using phoneGap instead of using jQuery mobile. Is it possible?

Comment: PhoneGap or Cordova use to build application through your web application. it is separate framework. they doesn't compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is UI Framework for building web application and PhoneGap is a JavaScript framework which allows you to access native device functionality.

For example consider cases.

- Case 1: You can develop mobile web app using Jquery Mobile.
- Case 2: If you want to access device hardware for native device
  functionality, you have Phone-gap in addition to your UI framework
  that can be anything not just jQuery Mobile. You can package it for different platform (like iOS, Android etc) i.e., an Hybrid App. Approach depends on your requirement.

Comment: that means, I cant design UI with phoneGap?

Comment: I would say that's not the power of Phonegap or Cordova.......What if I ask you to access mobile device contacts using web app only? Will it be possible?

Comment: So phoneGap provides me the advantage of accessing device content or features(like camera etc..,)

Comment: yup there you go...You found the track :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things:

**phonegap** is used to run web application as mobile app it start a web view and run your website

**jquery mobile** is framework for website compatibility for mobiles

for writing phonegap app you need to write website, therefore tou can use jquery mobile to write this website

Phonegap also give you api for native functionality - [phonegap home page](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

https://cordova.apache.org/

PhoneGap or Cordova use to build application through your web application. it is separate framework. they doesn't compare

You may change UI through native platform code. but you should not change. Already you have web project. You can access to platform features(camera, wifi, connection).